# Overwrite docker image with latest tag in artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I am currently Pushing same image twice one with tag number and another with latest tag to artifactory.

For the next release I would like to overwrite the image with latest tag with the new image that contains latest tag.   Below is the way I am trying from Azure devops build

```
Docker Build Command:
     $(docker_registry)/$(Build.Repository.Name):$(BuildNbr)
Docker Push Command
      $(docker_registry)/$(Build.Repository.Name):$(BuildNbr)
```

Same above with latest tag, then

```
docker pull $(docker_registry)/imageName:latest

docker rmi --force $(docker_registry)/imageName:latest   //removing latest image from artifactory NOT WORKING

docker pull $(docker_registry)/imageName:$(BuildNbr)

docker tag $(docker_registry)/imageName:$(BuildNbr) $(docker_registry)/imageName:latest

docker push $(docker_registry)/imageName:latest
```

Somehow the above flow is not working and the latest image is not getting overwritten.

Am I doing any mistake ? I believe rmi command will not delete the image from artifactory.

Comment: docker rmi won't delete image from artifactory

Comment: last push should overwrite though

Comment: Does the user you are authenticating with had delete permissions?

Comment: I am able to delete the image from Artifactory web console using the same credentials.  I am not sure why it is not overwriting the image in artifactory, any hunches ?

Comment: are you getting any error when trying to push? do you see any relevant error in the artifactory log files? do you see the push request in the request log?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it through the include/exclude pattern for your permissions. You can create a new Permission Target that gives overwrite/delete permissions to tags with "latest" in it:

1. Remove the include pattern `**`
2. Add the include pattern `**/latest/*`
3. Add only the required docker repositories (for example "docker local")
4. Add anyone to this permission target that needs to be able to overwrite/delete.

[image]

Then, for all other permission targets, which defines the remainder of the tags (1.1, 1.2, etc), do not provide overwrite/delete permissions. With this, you will be able to overwrite the latest and not other tags.

You can read about include/exclude patterns as they relate to permission targets [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions#ManagingPermissions-CreatingaPermissionTarget).